# ASP Classic - Displaying results from MSSQL2000 stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

I am not very well versed in ASP, but that is what my client's site is written in so I am taking the easy way out.

Basically, I am trying to display results from a stored procedure based on a value I give.  There should and ARE multiple records being returned from the SP so I am not sure if I need to loop through them, or what.

So far, I have

```
set rst2 = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst2.open "exec zSProc_Name of SP " & resID,conL  

while not rst2.eof
            Response.Write(rst2.Fields("fieldname1").value & ", ")
            Response.Write(rst2.Fields("fieldname2").value & "<br />")
            Response.Write(rst2.Fields("fieldname3").value & "<br />")
            Response.Write(rst2.Fields("fieldname4").value & "<br />")
        rst2.movenext
        wend

set rst2 = nothing 'Clear up memory used
rst2.close
```

can anyone clear up what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: i found an example but using oracle... maybe it can help you somehow: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229919

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is... Are you seeing the results you expect? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning `Nothing` to `rst2` before calling `Close` so that will result in a "..object not set" error.  Swap the lines around to fix that.

Potentially you are getting `resID` from data sent to the page by the client.  If so your use of string concatenation to create a SQL batch is exposing the site to a SQL injection attack.

Instead you should use a ADODB.Command object to execute an SP instead of constructing SQL.  For an example consult [KB164485](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164485).

You are writing field values directly which most of the time will be ok but if any text contains characters such as `<` or `&` it won't render properly.  Wrap values in `Server.HTMLEncode` methods.

Comment: Funny how transposing two lines will fix something. And great call on the SQL attack. While I am not getting the resID from them, there are other scripts that DO get info from the user, so I will use this article.

And to be clear, you recommend: Response.Write(rst2.Fields("fieldname2").Server.HTMLEncode(value)? or
Response.Write(Server.HTMLEncode(rst2.Fields("fieldname2").value.... ?
Thanks again!

Comment: @NarfFlarf: The latter, I doubt an ADODB.Field object would have any knowledge of HTML encoding ;)

Comment: LOL!! Sometimes logic wins the hand, right? Thanks again Anthony.